# BigQuery OAuth access token on Java App Engine dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-bigquery

I'm adding BigQuery support to my App Engine app and getting stuck on OAuth2, specifically when testing on the dev server (deployed test works).

The most App-Engine specific and current advice I could find, here:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-appengine

Suggests this:

```
if (System.getProperty("OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN") != null) {
    // Good for testing and localhost environments, where no AppIdentity is available.
    return new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(System.getenv("OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN"));
}
```

What would I set the OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN to? Is this something I'd hardcode in my settings (I thought access tokens were temporary?) or would I set it programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of an answer, my workaround was to create a GoogleCredential using the process described here:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization#service-accounts-server

I therefore use the GAE-specific instructions when deployed and use the key-file rigmarole when on the dev server.

Comment: That's perfect! That's one option, the other one would have been using your user authentication token - but the service account is better for automated tests.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Where can I find my user authentication token?